# Backup database with Entity Framework on ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql

I have an interesting case. I lost access to an Azure subscription. However, I still have access to publishing an ASP.Net application, because I configured a publishing profile, which still works. Note, that this is nothing illegal - internal company policies regarding VS subscriptions; enough to say, that application is mine, written by me, maintained by me etc.

I need to create a backup of the database, but **the only thing I can do is to publish the application**. Application obviously have connection string embedded in settings, but I cannot connect to the database due to firewall settings (Azure services only). So I need to find a way to dump the data with a controller and action.

So far I managed to dump most tables manually (eg. `var data = context.Table.ToList();`) and then output results into view. However, this won't export internal ASP.Net tables, which I cannot access directly (eg. user/role claims etc.)

Keep in mind, that we're talking about Azure SQL, which differs from the regular SQL Server.

How can I back up the database, so that I can migrate application to a different subscription?

Comment: What do you mean "internal ASP.NET tables"? You're talking about an old ASP.NET Membership schema? Why can't you just use ADO.NET to read the data from those tables? You know how to write a SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

If you also can publish your webapp. You can create a `API` function and invoke it. Something like: https://yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net/backup/start.

You can create `PROCEDURE`, and run it to generate `.bak` file to blob（
The premise is that you need to know blob related information.）.

Sample code like :

[C# SQL Server backup of a remote database to the remote default backup location without direct access to the remote location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062201/c-sharp-sql-server-backup-of-a-remote-database-to-the-remote-default-backup-loca)